# What is next letter in sequence: B, D, G, J, L, ___?

Tags: number-sequence, sequence, letter-sequence

My answer is P. But I am not sure as there is not sufficient data to support this.

B(2), ____, G(7), ____, L(12), _____ (alternating sequence of difference 5: 2, 7, 12, 17,...)

____, D(4), ____, J(10), ____, P(16) (alternating sequence of difference 6: 4, 10, 16, ...)

Is this correct answer? Or can someone come up with different answer with better logic?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Where did you get this puzzle from? If it's not a puzzle you created yourself, you need to credit the original source, otherwise it can be considered plagiarism.

Comment: My friend sent it to me. He was asked in an in-person interview for the trader role.

Comment: I think 2 datapoints for the even-indexed letters is not enough to support  your idea. That said, this is a pretty short sequence

Comment: If it's an interview question it might be purposefully designed not to have an obvious answer, to get an idea about how the candidate is thinking an exploring options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe the answer is

> N

because

> the sequence consists of every other consonant starting with B:

> (a) **B** C **D** (e) F **G** H (i) **J** K **L** M **N** (o) P **Q** R **S** ….

Answer (score 8):

I think the next letter could be

> M

As these are

> The "voiced" consonants (consonants which require the use of vocal cords) in alphabetical order.

Reference

> https://www.thoughtco.com/voiced-and-voiceless-consonants-1212092

Answer (score 2):

I agree strongly with the comments and the trend of the answers so far: This is likely a question without a clear answer that was asked to try to learn something about the interview candidate's thinking/pattern recognition processes.  The pattern isn't simple enough to confidently identify a single answer.  If it had been every 3rd letter, B,E,H,K,N,__ for instance, then while other patterns could definitely be identified, the obvious answer would be Q.

This pattern isn't that simple, and I can't see how any of the solutions given are better or worse than the others.

My solution (I will suggest that as an interviewer I would not be thrilled with this as anything other than an initial observation.): M

> I noticed that the patterns of skipped letters is 1 - 2 - 2 - 1.  This could repeat.
>  B (skip 1) D (skip 2) G (skip 2) J (skip 1) L **(skip 1) M**

Again, not a clever pattern and not well supported by the available data - I just felt that I should include my own solution to the problem rather than a just commentary about the questioner's reasoning.

Comment: Why would the pattern repeat every 4 steps when the simpler option of repeating every 3 steps is also possible?

Comment: That's just another of the many options.  Actually, 1-2-2-1-1-2-2-1 looks prettier to me than 1-2-2-1-2-2.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis That's kind of the point.  You saw the 1 as the new beginning of a repeating cycle while I saw it as the end of a symmetric cycle.

Answer (score 0):

It could be O

> Convert to integers, 2, 4, 7, 10, 13.
>  deltas are: 2, 3, 3, 2.
>  continue pattern 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3 -> letter L+3 = O

Or it could be N

> deltas are: 2, 3, 3, 2.
>  continue with doubles 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2 => letter L+2 = N

Or maybe L

> deltas are: 2, 3, 3, 2,
>  2nd deltas are: 1, 0, -1.
>  continue 1, 0, -1, -2, deltas are 2, 3, 3, 2, 0 => letter L+0 = L

Or maybe O after all

> deltas are: 2, 3, 3, 2,
>  follow Morse-Thue pattern 2332322332232332... => letter L+3 = O

Or it could be P

> There are two interleaved sequences:
>  B, G, L: progression 5
>  D, J, ?: progression 6 => letter J+6 = P

As infinitezero and Jason Patterson suggest, the question is not to find the correct answer but to see how you think.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is M or N or O. Reasons below.
(BTW my reasoning might be weird and difficult to understand).

Because:

BDGJL

My way of doing it is kind of using math here. The number is equivalent to the amount of letters that space the "other letters". Says B to D. D is two letter after B. So using this logic:

B+2=D   D+3=G   G+3=J   J+2=L

So to solve this, i need to follow the pattern. Before B was A, so A+1=B. So I think the pattern is. *x*+1, *x*+2, *x*+3, *x*+3, *x*+2, *x*+1.

With that reasoning of the (+1), the answer is M. If you go:

*x*+2, *x*+3, *x*+3, *x*+2, *x*+2, then the answer is N.

If you go:

*x*+2, *x*+3, *x*+3, *x*+2, *x*+3. Then the answer is O.

As I said before, my reasoning might not be understandable, I understand.